# cropping and slicing multiple images in a folder using python PIL or cv2, then saving in another folder

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library, slice

I am trying to crop all images in a folder and save them in another folder. Then split all the images I have cropped using the `image_slicer` library.

I know a similar question like this has been asked but the difference is that I don't want the original folder to contain the cropped photos.

Here is my code so far; it runs but does nothing:

```
from PIL import Image        
import image_slicer
import os

path = 'BeforeAfter'
arr = os.listdir(path)

def crop():
    for i in arr:
        if os.path.isfile(i):
            img = Image.open(i)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(i)
            left = 66.6
            top = 37.4
            right = 1212.4
            bottom = 550.7
            imCrop = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
            imCrop.save("CroppedImages/", "PNG", quality= 100)
            # tiles = image_slicer.slice(toslice, 12, save=False)
            # image_slicer.save_tiles(tiles, directory='frames')
crop()
```

Comment: What does `print(os.listdir('BeforeAfter'))` output?

Comment: What does print(os.listdir('BeforeAfter')) outputs an array containing all my images